# How to return a defined type (array) from a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return, typedef

I get an error, when I try to return a value of type verylongint from a function. What is the correct way to return?
verylongint is an array of the type long long int and is defined in line 5.
the function returning a verylongint should be string2verylongint(char* n).  The output of the compiler is below the source code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 63

typedef long long verylongint[63];

char* verylongint2string(verylongint n);
verylongint string2verylongint(char* n);

main(){
    verylongint n;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)n[i]=0; //initialize
    n[0]= 999999999999999999;
    n[1]= 999999999999999999;
    n[2]= 2323232311;
    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(n));

    verylongint m;
    m = string2verylongint("123999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");

    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(m));
}

verylongint string2verylongint(char* n){
    char m[18]; // first long long element, which is not zero, as string
    sscanf(n, "%[^9]", m);
    long long n1; // as long long
    sscanf(m, "%lld", &n1);
    int length= strlen(n)-strlen(m); // length of string without the first element
    int i;
    verylongint k; //return value
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)k[i]=0; //initialize
    for(i=0; i<length/18; i++){ // length/18 is the number of elements (without 1st)
        k[i]=999999999999999999;
    }   
    k[i] = n1;

    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(k));

    return k;
}

char* verylongint2string(verylongint n){
    char* string = (char*) malloc(18*63*sizeof(char));//18 is the length of the biggest number
                            //63 is the length of the long-array
    int i=SIZE;
    while(n[--i]==0);
    //string=n[i];
    sprintf(string, "%lld", n[i]); //first number, which is not zero
    while(--i>=0){ //adding the biggest number
        strcat(string,"999999999999999999"); //the biggest number(one char smaller than lld)
    }

    return string;
}
```

Output:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ gcc verylongint.c -o vli
verylongint.c:9:13: error: ‘string2verylongint’ declared as function returning an array
 verylongint string2verylongint(char* n);
             ^
verylongint.c: In function ‘main’:
verylongint.c:21:4: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘verylongint’ from type ‘int’
  m = string2verylongint("123999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");
    ^
verylongint.c: At top level:
verylongint.c:26:13: error: ‘string2verylongint’ declared as function returning an array
 verylongint string2verylongint(char* n){
             ^
verylongint.c: In function ‘string2verylongint’:
verylongint.c:42:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  return k;
  ^
verylongint.c:42:2: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

Comment: C functions can't return arrays by value. Put it into a struct.

Comment: or decide who (caller or callee) is going to allocate the memory and use a pointer

Comment: The very first thing you need you learn to program in C is that 99% of the time, caller need to provide container to bring out the result, rather than return a container with the result provided by the callee.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, arrays can't be the return value of a function.  You need to pass in the array as a parameter.  Since arrays passed into functions decay to a pointer to the first element, changes to the array in the function will be reflected in the caller.

Also, verylongint2string allocates a buffer for its result but is never freed anywhere, causing a memory leak.  Given how you're using it, you could instead use a fixed length static variable, although that would mean you can't call it twice in the same statement or use it in a multithreaded application without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you, im working on a computer science project and i was trying to shorten something by making a function do all the work and return the array but a pack of incompatable type talk and errors were happening.. so this is what was wrong ;-;

Answer (score 0):

C language exposes a very strange behavior toward arrays.
You can find tons of reference to standards about decaying of arrays to pointers special behavior is some cases, etc. Those comment come from reading (and in some cases misinterpreting the standards) not having lived development of the C language from the beginning in the 70s.
C was born as an intermediary language between an assembler and an high level language for the purpose of programming OS chunks of code where side to side with complex data structures it was requested to also to access HW registers, handle hw I/O and the like.

At that time reserving a memory area to hold a number of variable of same type was called an array. Then how to use such data? Simple, you can access all the array data using the memory area base address. **But this is incidentally the address of the first element of the array**. From then on we use to say that any reference to an array name is equivalent to a reference to the address of its first element:

`array => &array[0];`.

The real reason behind this is that the code generated by the compiler in the assembler (the low level) side would be like:

```
array db 10 dup (0)
```

For whichever reference to array in the code:

```
lea eax, array
```

It is the base address of the array.

More than a spec of the language it was a practical rule to associate the array name to the address of its first element.

But also a pointer variable contains an address, so if we get an address, should it come from an array or from a pointer, we can apply same modes to access data:

```
movsx eax, byte ptr [eax+4]    //read in eax, extendid the sign, the 5th element of the array pointed by eax
```

There is just a small difference in emitted code. Suppose we have:

```
int a[10];
int *p = a;
foo(a[3], p[3]);
```

Will compile to:

```
a DW 10 DUP(?)   //An array of 10 ints uninitialized
p DW a           //a pointer initialized to a address
....
lea eax, p    //Get the address of the pointer
mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax]    //Get the base address of array memory
mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+0xC]  //0xC is the offset of the 3rd element (3 * 4bytes)
push eax      //Push second parameter
lea eax, a    //Get the address of the array
mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+0xC]  //0xC is the offset of the 3rd element (3 * 4bytes)
push eax      //Push first parameter (C pushes parameters right to left)
call foo
```

As you can see the only difference is that using a pointer we have to read the array base address from it, while with an array the assembler give us right the address of data.

Then the access to the data is exactly the same. That's because a pointer and an array in C behaves almost the same in many cases. Once again a practical rule become a language rule...

At that time, when memory was counted in **K**ilo**B**ytes (not GB!) to move around chunk of memory was a nonsense. From here come another rule: **an array have to be passed to a function only by reference** and this job is automatically made by compiler.
Finally **a function can never returns an array**.

Now going back to your code there are 2 errors: you cannot return an array from a function, and **you don't have to return local variables** because they exist only in the function scope that ends when the function returns giving back garbage and UB (Undefined Behavior).

But you can create an array from dynamic memory using a pointer, and return this pointer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 63

typedef long long verylongint[63];

char *verylongint2string(verylongint *n);
verylongint *string2verylongint(char *n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    verylongint n;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        n[i] = 0;   //initialize
    n[0] = 999999999999999999;
    n[1] = 999999999999999999;
    n[2] = 2323232311;
    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(&n));

    verylongint *m;    //m now is a pointer to the array
    m = string2verylongint("123999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");

    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(m));
}

verylongint *string2verylongint(char *n)
{
    char m[18]; // first long long element, which is not zero, as string
    sscanf(n, "%[^9]", m);
    long long n1;   // as long long
    sscanf(m, "%lld", &n1);
    int length = strlen(n) - strlen(m); // length of string without the first element
    int i;
    verylongint *k = malloc(sizeof(verylongint));   //return value
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        (*k)[i] = 0;    //initialize
    for (i = 0; i < length / 18; i++)
    {   // length/18 is the number of elements (without 1st)
        (*k)[i] = 999999999999999999;
    }
    (*k)[i] = n1;

    printf("%s\n", verylongint2string(k));

    return k;
}

char *verylongint2string(verylongint *n)
{
    char *string = (char *)malloc(18 * 63 * sizeof(char));  //18 is the length of the biggest number
    //63 is the length of the long-array
    int i = SIZE;
    while (n[--i] == 0) ;
    //string=n[i];
    sprintf(string, "%lld", (*n)[i]);   //first number, which is not zero
    while (--i >= 0)
    {   //adding the biggest number
        strcat(string, "999999999999999999");   //the biggest number(one char smaller than lld)
    }

    return string;
}
```

Enjoy.